# Kurento Custom Module: Media Object not available (Code:40108)

Tags: kurento

I am learning how to create Kurento Custom Module by following the guide here: http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mastering/develop_kurento_modules.html

As a fast-track approach in learning, I cloned the java client and C++ module from Github that is used by the Chroma Tutorial: 
http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/java/module-chromafilter.html

I was able to build and run the Chroma module successfully.

So the next thing I tried to do is to make simple modifications to the source codes, makefiles etc by renaming all occurrences of "chroma" to "emotion" ("Chroma" to "Emotion", "CHROMA" to "EMOTION") including the module name and function/method names. The aim is to get the exact same Chroma Tutorial to run, except that I can be sure that it is now making API calls to my new custom module (which should function exactly the same too).

After much effort, I was able to compile successfully both the C++ custom module (kms-emotion) as well as the Java client application (kurento-emotion).

However, there seems to be something wrong still. I am not getting video from the remote stream on the browser. Looking at the logs in /var/log/kurento-media-server, there is this error:

```
2016-10-17 19:27:48,204852 3488 [0x00007f0e8cff9700]   debug KurentoWebSocketTransport WebSocketTransport.cpp:422 processMessage()  Message: >{"id":5,"method":"create","params":{"type":"EmotionFilter","constructorParams":{"mediaPipeline":"6842e4d3-782a-4ce7-8617-9daf72a0b1d4_kurento.MediaPipeline","window":{"topRightCornerY":5,"__module__":"emotion","topRightCornerX":5,"height":40,"__type__":"WindowParam","width":40}},"properties":{},"sessionId":"3fe8b253-c4c1-421f-bddb-b6f2c6674683"},"jsonrpc":"2.0"}<
2016-10-17 19:27:48,206450 3488 [0x00007f0e8cff9700]   error filterelement             kmsfilterelement.c:139 kms_filter_element_set_filter() <kmsfilterelement0>  Invalid factory "emotion", element cannot be created
2016-10-17 19:27:48,206895 3488 [0x00007f0e8cff9700]   debug KurentoWebSocketTransport WebSocketTransport.cpp:424 processMessage()  Response: >{"error":{"code":40108,"data":{"type":"MEDIA_OBJECT_NOT_AVAILABLE"},"message":"Media Object not available"},"id":5,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

I have built and installed my module (libkmsemotionmodule.so) in the right place (as shown below), and restarted the kurento media server..

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kurento/modules/total 848
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  26920 Sep 10 18:55 libkmschromamodule.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 121128 Oct  1 00:12 libkmscoremodule.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  35112 Sep 10 19:01 libkmscrowddetectormodule.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 104744 Oct  1 01:33 libkmselementsmodule.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 503539 Oct 17 18:57 libkmsemotionmodule.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  39192 Oct  1 02:14 libkmsfiltersmodule.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  26904 Sep 10 18:58 libkmsplatedetectormodule.so
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: ok just to add... i found that i could replicate the same error with the original kurento chroma module by getting from git and compiling it...

my procedure of compiling kms-chroma is as follows..
    1) git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kms-chroma.git
    2) cd kms-chroma
    3) mkdir build
    4) cd build
    5) cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr && make
    6) sudo make install
    7) sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 stop
    8) sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 start

Comment: if i install it via "sudo apt-get install kms-chroma-6.0" ... the module works fine... so what did i miss...?

Answer (score 0):

ok... i managed to find the problem... my system has OpenCV 3.1 installed... and seems that the module is not compatible (or conflicting) with OpenCV 3.1 even though there was no issue with the compilation... when i downloaded the source and build OpenCV 2.4.13.1 on my system and recompile the module... it is able to run now...

this might be a problem for me because i am trying to integrate some existing C++ application as a kurento custom module and exposing its functionality to the web application... and the application uses OpenCV 3.x... but that will be a separate problem...